# How to run android emulator in ubuntu and show in windows

Tags: android, ubuntu, emulation, xserver

My PC has win7 OS, and I install ubuntu14.04 in vmware.

All my work with android is in ubuntu.  Using xming and xshell with redirecting X11, I can show the eclipse, android stuio and SDK manager GUI in windows.

But when I lunch android emulator, it report error.
ERROR: Could not create SDL2 window: Couldn't find matching GLX visual

I try some answers, but they can't fix this error.

I try other X server, such as Xmanager and VcXsrv.
The Xmanager can show the emulator GUI in windows, but the emulator screen is all black.

The VcXsrv has the same error with xming.

I finally try the Xpra. Xpra can show the emulator OK. I can click and swip on emulator screen, but after I finised other work and come back with the emulator, the click has no response.

How to fix that ERROR or How to make Xpra work OK?

Comment: You're hitting a bug in the Ubuntu package, updating to the latest version from xpra.org will fix this.